# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_&lt;ext&gt;.dll'

Tags: php, apache, nextcloud

I recently set up a nextcloud on a debian stretch server and it is running smoothly so far. 
But I just discovered some entries in the nextcloud logs which are kind of irritating.

> [PHP] Error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_<ext>.dll' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/php_<ext>.dll (/usr/lib/php/20180731/php_<ext>.dll: cannot open shared object file: No >such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/php_<ext>.dll.so >(/usr/lib/php/20180731/php_<ext>.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) at Unknown#0

It seems the server does not know which library he actually wants to load.

Any ideas what could cause it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `php.ini` file, search for .dll, look for all uncommented lines loading DLL's, make sure there isn't anything weird.

Also try searching for `ini`, and seeing if any other ini files were parsed, or any additional directories scanned, and check those too.

After removing the offending line, remember to restart Apache/NginX.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I accidentially removed a semicolon in front of a comment in my php.ini.